# flutter url_launcher doesn't dial tel scheme on ios simulator

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I want phone dialing to occur when FAB is pressed. I tried different methods but my app either throws _Exception (Exception: Could not launch +*************) or does not respond at all.

For example, with my current code example, when I click the button, there is no change in the console or the screen.

```
  static FloatingActionButton buildCallFab(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) async {
      final Uri launchUri = Uri(
        scheme: 'tel',
        path: phoneNumber,
      );
      await launchUrl(launchUri);
    }

    return FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: 'callButton',
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.bwyRed,
      tooltip: 'Ara $phoneNumber',
      onPressed: () {
        _makePhoneCall('+************');
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
```

ınfo.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Bwy</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>bwy</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>sms</string>
  <string>tel</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="bwy"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyBuqpVE5wMhXR29mitzgRzJMC8LnZQtQAI"/>
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does the same code work on Android?

Comment: sorry i am only running it on ios Simulator. And I haven't run it on real device yet, I hope the problem is only in the simulator
 Future<void> _makePhoneCall() async {
      Uri launchUri = Uri.parse('tel:+1-555-010-9999');
      await launchUrl(launchUri);
    } / this didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the number you are submitting matches the format listed in the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#supported-url-schemes) package. The example they give is this: `tel:+1-555-010-9999`